# Unsolved reference 'Tk'?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn tkinter and how to make GUIs with it, but PyCharm is giving me an error as "Unresolved reference 'Tk' "
My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
```

Comment: Did you just named your or any file in the current working directory as `tkinter.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a file in your project called `tkinter.py` that's shadowing the `tkinter` module. (The path to the "real" `tkinter` would be something like `Python/Python310/lib/tkinter/__init__.py`, whereas the path `tkinter.py` in the error message indicates a file in your project's root path.)

To fix the problem, rename or move your `tkinter.py` file.